# How to I make a .cfg file for CS:GO on a Mac with TextEdit?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I am really annoyed to the fact that my mac will not let me make a .cfg file for custom keybinds in CS: GO. I use textedit and I have tried to rename the .txt to .cfg but my autoexec file always results as: 
autoexec.cfg.txt
 How does one fix this or is this a fixable problem? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to save it as autoexec.cfg? Try to write in the titlebar autoexec.cfg. If you want to rename it you have to display the filetype first and remove the txt. **I have no MAC gussing here**

Comment: That is what I tried and the dang file would just go to autoexec.cfg.txt

Comment: [This](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11135/how-do-i-create-a-file-with-a-custom-file-extension) may help you...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I asked this on the normal stack overflow site and it was fixed.

Comment: Stackoverflow will eat you alive if you post that there.

Comment: You're having trouble managing file extensions in the mac filemanager. This is only tangentially related to a game at *best*.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness why is that? in kinda new to their site. Isn't it a question related to software AND the game? why have people closed this? its not off topic!

Comment: @Neffer_23 Stackoverflow is for programming questions, not how to use a computer questions. That is what superuser.com is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal on your mac, cd to the directory where you want that file and type

```
touch autoexec.cfg
```

This will create the file for you. For more information about this command, type `man touch`.

*(Or  `info touch` if the previous command is too misogynistic for you)*

Comment: how does this fix the counterstrike configuration?

Comment: @Neffer_23 It creates the file you need with the correct file ending.